# (Python) Is there a way to clear all entry boxes in a Tkinter UI in one line?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a Tkinter UI for a fairly simple calculator that all works fine, and I have a clear button to clear all entry boxes. I'd rather have one line of code to clear all 40+ boxes than 40+ lines to clear each individually, and was wondering if there was a Tkinter command that could do the same as `ent.delete(0, END)` but for all entries?

Comment: just use a loop, iterate over the widgets (preferred if you save them all in some list or use a dedicated container for all of them (because then `.winfo_children` could be used in a safer manner but list is probably better)), then just call on each of them the `.delete` method

Comment: Instead of one line, you can use two. Why is it important to do it in one line? You can store the widgets in a list, and then iterate over the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be sufficient:

```
[widget.delete(0, tk.END) for widget in root.winfo_children() if isinstance(widget, tk.Entry)]
```

It uses list comprehension to loop through all the children of root and does `.delete()` if the child is an `Entry`

**Implementation:**

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

def create_entries(root, amount):
    for _ in range(amount):
        tk.Entry(root).pack(pady=2)


def clear():
    [widget.delete(0, tk.END) for widget in root.winfo_children() if isinstance(widget, tk.Entry)]


create_entries(root, 5)

clear_btn = tk.Button(root, text="clear", padx=10, command=clear)
clear_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**NOTE:**
I should point out that this is probably not best practice but I dont really know.
It creates a list but doesnt assign it to anything so essentially it just does what you intended

**EDIT:**
Also consider the following if you want to clear every entry, even if it is inside a different widget. This is to be used only if you are sure that every single entry in the whole application should be cleared

```
def clear(root):
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        if not isinstance(widget, tk.Entry):
            clear(widget)
        elif isinstance(widget, tk.Entry):
            widget.delete(0, tk.END)
```

Also note that, I used a normal for loop for this, because as noted in the comments, it is better

Comment: yes, that is a bad practice to use a list comprehension for something other than creating a usable list, it's kinda silly and you get an unneeded list, so just use a `for` loop instead, besides a `for` loop will be more readable, also use `if isinstance(widget, tk.Entry)`

Comment: @Matiiss Yea i had a feeling it would be so, I would use a for loop but for the sake of the one-liner. I changed it to `if isinstance(widget, tk.Entry)` but why is this better? I assume since an entry widget in an _instance_ of `tk.Entry` class?

Comment: first of it supports inherited types, it also can check against multiple types and it also is more self-explanatory, perhaps, other reasons

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info

Comment: So it wasn't working for me when I just copy/pasted the relevant section into my clear function, but I had a little look and what I think I need to do is tell it to delete the entries in a specific frame- I have one frame for all my labels and entries, then a frame below for my buttons, and the `window.winfo_children()` line returns a list of the frames as opposed to the widgets in the frames. I'm assuming I just need another command to direct the function to the right frame and then it will work, although I am not sure how. Apologies for all this, I am still very new to Tkinter...

Comment: Well, if you know which frame it is, you can just do `frame.winfo_children()`

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try that... I tried `window.frame.winfo_children()` which didn't work... Thanks so much for your help guys :)

Comment: If the answer helped, feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it. Also check out the edit, it may be helpful.